# "Let's" vs. "lets": which is correct?

Tags: verbs, contractions, transitive-verbs

Say I'm promoting a product. Which is correct?

> - [Product] let's you [do something awesome].
> - [Product] lets you [do something awesome].

Or neither?

Comment: The more I think about it the more I think that neither is correct and it should rephrased...

Comment: @jeffmaphone, really, the second sentence is just fine. It’s not fancy, but there’s nothing wrong with it at all. “ *Facebook* lets you *connect with long lost friends*.” “ *StackExchange* lets you *ask and answer questions on most any topic*.” “ *Google* lets you *find the web page you were looking for*.”

Comment: So it would seem.  Perhaps I over-thought it.  I don't have a real dictionary at work, and I was having trouble finding authoritative proof of the acceptance of "lets" as a real word on the Internet.  Which is why I turned to the experts here.  Frequently though I find it's easier to reword something than to debate its correctness: "[Product] enables you to [do something awesome]" conveys the point just as well with no potential errors or debate over correctness.  :)  Thanks for responding.

Comment: If you replace 'you' with 'us' and pluralise it, then contract it to "let's", you get 'These products let's do awesome things'. This is definitely wrong. Just an observation.

Comment: @jeffamaphone Unless you do not have a computer, you always have a real dictionary. There are plenty of those online.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

*Let’s* is the English cohortative word, meaning “let us” in an exhortation of the group including the speaker to do something.

*Lets* is the third person singular present tense form of the verb *let* meaning to permit or allow.

In the questioner’s examples, the sentence means to say “Product (allows/permits you to) do something awesome”, so the form with *lets* is correct.

Answer (score 34):

The second one is correct.

*Let's* is a contraction of *let us*. "Let's go to the ballgame today!"

*Lets* is the third-person singular simple present indicative form of [*let*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/let) -- but of course we all knew that already....
It means *allows*, which looks like what you want to convey here.

Answer (score 17):

Here's an easy way to figure out which to use: replace the word *lets* with the words *let us*.  If the sentence still makes sense, then use the contractual form.  Let's try a few examples:

> 1. Lets/**let's** see how it can be done.  `(should be Let's)`
> 2. Flubber let's/**lets** you jump high. `(should be lets)`
> 3. **Let's**/lets go to the movie after dinner. `(should be Let's)`
> 4. This trick **lets**/let's us pick the right word. `(should be lets)`

Comment: An additional approach is to make the subject PLURAL, and then see which verb you are wont to pick: These products (...) you [do awesome things]. Obviously "let", not "let'".