# "Let's": similar contractions?

Tags: grammar, expressions, verbs, pronouns, contractions

First, I'm aware of this question: ["Let's" vs. "lets": which is correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3392/lets-vs-lets-which-is-correct)

What I want to know is if there are other similar constructions formed by contracting a verb with *"us"*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No there are no other contractions of words with **us** in the above specified form as in other contexts contractions ending with **'s** refer to contraction for **is, has or does** which is very informal and hence rarely seen. **Let us** is a special case that is used in forming the imperative mood in first person singular for **Let us**.
[Here is the link to the reference in case you wish to find further clarifications.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraction_(grammar)#English)
Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Additionally, *let's* is losing its sense of being a 1pl imperative and moving towards being a general imperative marker used with a variety of subjects. This is why you hear people say in informal speech, *Let's you call me after dinner*.

Comment: @JSBangs: It may be moving that way where you are, but I've never heard that in the UK. Yet :)

Comment: @JSBangs: I've never heard that usage in the US, either.

Comment: @JSB New to me too.

Comment: Hmm, contractions are *very* informal?  "He's" for "He is" is *very* informal?  I don't think so... but if it's on Wikipedia, it must be correct, right?  </sarcasm>

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard, I think ikartik90 was saying that contractions with *does* are very informal and rarely seen.

Comment: "Let's You and Him Fight", at least as old as "Popeye": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_You_and_Him_Fight, http://www.ericberne.com/games/games_people_play_LYAHF.htm, http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LetsYouAndHimFight