# Is it correct to say "Lets Answer me" or "Let's Answer me"?

Tags: grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Let's” vs. “lets”: which is correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3392/lets-vs-lets-which-is-correct)

Do they have different meaning?

Answer (score 3):

If Lets means "let us", then it requires the apostrophe. Although you can find many instances of "lets" with a quick Google, it is still not correct. Correct would be:

> Let's answer me.

I'm not quite sure what "Let's answer me" might mean, though. Could you care to provide a bit more context?