# Difference between Let, Let's and Lets?

Tags: meaning, grammar

Many people use "let, let's and lets" in conversation

What's the difference between them?

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Let's" vs. "lets": which is correct?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3392/lets-vs-lets-which-is-correct)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The verb in each construction is *let.*  It is usually used in the imperative mood:
*'Let* me go.'  *'Let* them eat cake.'  *'Let* him go without supper.'

However, it can also be used in the indicative:
'I *let* him go.'  'They *let* us eat cake.'  'We *let* him go without supper.'

*Let's* is a contraction of *let us.*  It is technically an imperative construction, but usually indicates a suggestion rather than an order: *'Let us* go to the ball.' *'Let's* go shopping.'  *'Let's* talk about flowers.'

*Lets* is conjugated for the third-person singular present tense, which is to say that it is used with singular nouns and the pronouns *he, she, it:*  'He *lets* me eat cake.'  'She sometimes *lets* her brother use the Super Nintendo.'  'The country *lets* me feel freer than the city.'

Comment: It is almost the same case with [Apostrophes – how to use them](http://www.mantex.co.uk/2009/08/30/english-language-apostrophes/)

Comment: Note that "Let's" is only used in the imperative, never the indicative. One would never write or say "They let's eat cake".

Comment: I read somewhere the phrase _"she let (no s) me borrow her car"_ , is it correct or wrong?

Comment: @MarcoDemaio That would be the past-tense form of the verb, which never takes an *-s*.

Comment: @Anonym that's right, cool. Thanks man!